# I need to make "Read more" animation React Native

Tags: react-native

I created a review component with a read more element, reviewComment initially displays 3 lines, and after clicking on read more it displays the full text. How can I add a text expansion animation? using animated from react native

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
   Image,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
 } from 'react-native';
import Layout from '../../../ui/components/Layout';
import FiveStarRating from './review-starRating';
import DateConverter from './review-dateConverter';

const Review = ({icon, name,date,rating,comment}: reviewProps) => {
  // Read More
  const [textShown, setTextShown] = useState(false);
  const [lengthMore, setLengthMore] = useState(false);
  const toggleNumberOfLines = () => {
    setTextShown(!textShown);
  };


  return (
    <Layout customWrapperStyle={style.reviewItem}>
      <Layout customWrapperStyle={style.reviewHeader}>
        <Layout customWrapperStyle={style.reviewerInfo}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: icon,
            }}
            style={style.reviewerIcon}></Image>
          <Layout>
            <Text style={style.reviewName}>{name}</Text>
          <DateConverter textStyles={style.reviewDate} publishTime={date}></DateConverter>
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
        <FiveStarRating rating={rating}></FiveStarRating>
      </Layout>

      <Layout>
          <Text
            numberOfLines={textShown ? undefined : 3}
            style={style.reviewComment}>
              {comment}
          </Text>

        <Text onPress={toggleNumberOfLines} style={style.readMore}>
          Read more
        </Text>

        <Layout customWrapperStyle={style.reviewLine}></Layout>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

I tried to make transitions by numberOfLines, but was unable to calculate the "ToValue" value in animated after the text was displayed and returned the value NaN

Comment: If you can figure out the height of a single line, you could just toggle the text component's height back and forth between 3*lineHeight and 'auto'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the text component's line height using the style prop; which allows you to know the line height.You can use the `onTextLayout` prop to get the total number of lines on android and ios (ios needs to briefly have all the text be visible); and  because `onTextLayout` doesnt work on the web you can use `onLayout` prop on the  to get the text view's height; and then divide it by lineHeight to get the line count. Then when you toggle showMore you go switch back and forth from the minLines and the maxLines: ([demo](https://snack.expo.dev/wUi37vgLKBQOdwBO_nNBC?platform=web)):

```js
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Platform, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

// sample data
const name = 'Title';
const comment = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et augue risus. Nullam sit amet nulla et nunc volutpat maximus sit amet ut sem. Pellentesque in bibendum nisl, eu bibendum lorem. Nam tincidunt arcu nec tincidunt rhoncus. Integer varius nulla at laoreet lobortis. Vestibulum a odio placerat, malesuada justo eu, rhoncus diam. Fusce ut nunc orci. Praesent dictum ornare placerat. Fusce augue nibh, fermentum nec tellus vitae, tristique efficitur nulla. Vivamus ornare euismod luctus. Nullam felis ex, tincidunt non justo sed, varius congue magna. `;
const isIos = Platform.OS == 'ios'
// use fontSize and line padding to create line height
const fontSize = 16;
const linePadding = 4;
const lineHeight = fontSize + linePadding;
const minLines = 4


export default function App() {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const [maxLines, setMaxLines] = useState(minLines);
  const currentLines = useSharedValue(minLines);
  const {height} = useWindowDimensions()
  // when false animated view will be set to screen dimensions so that all text is shown
  const [linesCalculated,setLinesCalcules] = useState(isIos ? false : true)
  const handleToggle = () => {
    const newVal = !showMore;
    currentLines.value = withTiming(newVal ? maxLines : minLines);
    setShowMore(newVal);
  };
  const animStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      // if lines arent calculated give view maximum height
      height: !linesCalculated ? height : currentLines.value * lineHeight,
    };
  });
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        {name} {maxLines}
      </Text>
      <Animated.View style={animStyle}>
        <Text
          style={styles.comment}
          onLayout={(e) => {
            // since onLayout works for divide by lineHeight to get maxLines
            if (Platform.OS == 'web')
              setMaxLines(Math.floor(e.nativeEvent.layout.height / lineHeight));
            
          }}
          onTextLayout={(e) => {
            // use onTextLayout to get number of lines
            if (Platform.OS == 'android')
              setMaxLines(e.nativeEvent.lines.length);
            // with the view taking up all screen space all lines should render
            if(isIos && !linesCalculated){
              setMaxLines(e.nativeEvent.lines.length)
              setLinesCalcules(true)
            }
          }}
          collaspable={false}
          >
          {comment}
        </Text>
      </Animated.View>
      <Text style={styles.textButton} onPress={handleToggle}>
        Read {showMore ? 'less' : 'more'}
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  comment: {
    lineHeight,
    fontSize,
    overflow:'visible'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  textButton: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: This code in your demo works on the web, but on Android it does not respond, just like in my project

Comment: If you switch `onLayout` to `onTextLayout` , and you  can get the maximum number of lines. That would mean refractoring the code to keep track of the visible lines rather than the actual height. This works for android but doesnt work for web or ios

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/B85xb0kP4gH4jCCjUhfse

Comment: I merged the android solution with the web solution. I cant really think of a clean way to get results on ios https://snack.expo.dev/_qnAaelPSHnP_vwHmJuk4?platform=web

Comment: updated answer with solution for both android and web

Comment: updated answer with solution for all platforms